# Atualizar ng-repeat fora do ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Possuo um menu fixo na parte superior, aonde as paginas são abertas através de routes no ng-view.

Em uma view X eu adiciono um novo elemento a minha base de dados, e no menu fixo eu utilizo ng-repeat para listar estes elementos.

Quando eu adiciono algo novo no banco este ng-repeat do menu fixo não é atualizado, somente se utilizar F5.

Existe alguma maneira de atualizar este ng-repeat que está no menu fixo (fora do ng-view) sem utilizar o F5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concordo 100% com o colega acima, segue um exemplo simples abaixo:

```
 var servico1 = function() { 
      var servico = this; 
      servico.listaInserido = [];

      servico.add = function(item) { servico.listaInserido.push(item) }
 }
 var controllerfixo = function($scope, servico1) { $scope.servico = servico1; }
 var controllerrelativo = function($scope, servico1) { $scope.servico = servico1; }

 var app = angular.module('app');
 app.service('servico1', servico1);
 app.controller('controlerfixo', controllerfixo);
 app.controller('controllerrelativo', controllerrelativo);
```

HTML

```
<ul class="fixo" ng-controller="controllerfixo">
   <li ng-repeat="item in servico.listaInserido">{{item}}</li>
<ul> 

<div ng-controller="controllerrelativo">
     <button ng-click="servico.add({ a: 1})">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão vamos ver o que rola.

Answer (score 2):

Um possível modelo pode implementar um serviço que é responsável por conter a coleção, exposta via um membro.

Injete este serviço no *controller* que alimenta a sua *view*, e vincule este membro ao `$scope` do sua *view* contendo o `ng-repeat`.

Utilize um método do serviço para forçar a atualização da lista sempre que necessário.